# i have this error when i try to compile

Tags: c, gcc

[my code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ae52bc7c9ad75023d879) (i am a newbie):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int numr(int max) {
    int num = 2;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if (num > max) {
        printf("option not available\n");
    }
    else {
        return num;
    }
}
```

I am trying to compile with gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10) amd64.

But i have this error:

```
usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: dans la fonction « _start »: /build/glibc-Ir_s5K/glibc 2.19/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:118: référence indéfinie vers « main »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: If this should be a runable program you need a function named `main` as the entry point for the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are compiling a program into an executable you need to define a main function. Otherwise pass the correct arguments to gcc to compile it into a library.

Comment: You might want to change your wording slightly: You don't compile into a library, you compile either into an *object* or into a *shared object.* A static library is something that is created with a different program on most platforms.